# ":last-of-type" or ".last()" when using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, pseudo-class

[:last-of-type (as of v1.9)](https://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/) vs [.last() (as of v1.4)](https://api.jquery.com/last/): Either method works, but can anyone tell me which is the better method based on efficiency?

Example:

```
$(".item").last();

$(".item:last-of-type");
```

".last()" has been around longer (as of v1.4).
Does JQuery have ":last-of-type" built-in, or is it just utilizing CSS and piggybacking on the browser's capability?  Can anyone confirm this?

It would seem to me that ":last-of-type" would be better when applicable if this is the case.

Comment: Why not run some jsperf tests?

Comment: In general, jQuery selectors will use native selectors when possible.

Comment: The selectors perform two different selections, no?

Comment: They don't do even remotely the same thing, `last()` just gets the last element in the collection, while `:last-of-type` queries the DOM and finds all elements that are last of it's type in that parent element, i.e. among siblings with the same tagname

Comment: I do understand the difference and I wasn't saying they do exactly the same thing.  I was trying to figure out which one I should use for efficiency.  You're right as far as comparison.  Maybe ":last" ([link](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)) rather than ":last-of-type" would have been a better example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.last()` is faster.

Note, the selectors perform different selections

[`:last-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/)

> **last-of-type selector**
>
> Description: Selects all elements that are the last among siblings of
>   the same element name.

[`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

> **.last()**
>
> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to the final one in
>   the set.

```js
console.time("lastOfType");
$(".item:last-of-type");
console.timeEnd("lastOfType");

console.time("last");
$(".item").last();
console.timeEnd("last");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: I understand the differences. Thanks for pointing that out.  
Do you know why "last()" is more efficient?

Comment: `.last()` only selects last element of selector or collection. `:last-of-type` can select multiple elements.

Comment: I tried `$(".item:last")` vs `$(".item").last()` and still found it to be even slower.  I still don't actually understand that part of why it would be slower... :-/

Comment: @JoePC Have not checked all of the jQuery `:` selectors; not sure if they generally take greater time to return result than single selector chained to filtering function. Internally jQuery has to parse `:pseudo` selector string before selecting an element from `document`. Are the descriptions of `.last()` and `:last` the same at jQuery documentation?